# Use of @Parameters annotation in junit 4.11-SNAPSHOT

Tags: java, scala, junit

I want to make use of the new functionality in the latest build of junit in order to name my parameterized tests

I have the following two tests written in java & scala, but the scala test generates a compiler error:

> error: unknown annotation argument name: name @Parameters(name =
>   "{0}") def data: util.Collection[Array[AnyRef]] =
>   util.Arrays.asList(Array("x"), Array("y"), Array("z"))

What is the difference in implementation causing this error?

#### java

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameters;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;

import static org.junit.Assert.fail;

@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class ParameterizedTest {
    @Parameters(name = "{0}")
    public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[]{"x"}, new Object[]{"y"}, new Object[]{"z"});
    }

    @Test
    public void foo() {
        fail("bar");
    }
}
```

#### scala

```
import java.util
import org.junit.Assert._
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized._

@RunWith(classOf[Parameterized])
class ParameterizedScalaTest {
  @Test def foo() {
    fail("bar")
  }
}

object ParameterizedScalaTest {
  @Parameters(name = "{0}") def data: util.Collection[Array[AnyRef]] = util.Arrays.asList(Array("x"), Array("y"), Array("z"))
}
```

Comment: It may be using a different `Parameters` class for the annotation in scala. Try fully-qualifying the type and see what happens.

Comment: Are you importing the same/correct Parameters annotation?

Comment: It is the same annotation class (org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the issue here is due to junit-dep.jar being on the classpath through a transient dependency on jMock 2.4.0

Removing that fixed the compiler error, odd that this is an issue for scalac but not javac.

Comment: Also, if you ask me, when using Parameterized tests, you should use a defined constructor with a number of arguments equal to the column size of your Iterable ArrayList .  I am noticing that you aren't doing that in your example.  You should think about it.

Answer (score 0):

Because @Parameters is defined as an inner, you seem to need to give the full name.

Try

```
@Parameters(Parameters.name = "{0}")
```

At least, that is the only significant difference I can observe in the definitions of @Parameters and @Test, and this works:

```
@Test(timeout = 10)
```

Comment: It compiles fine for me.  I had to guess your scala version and imports though, and the only way I could reproduce your problem using 2.9.2 was to import "org.junit.runners._" or "org.junit.runners.Parameterized".  Perhaps you could update the question to include the imports.

Comment: I have added the imports - seems scalac resolved Parameterized to junit-dep.jar and javac to junit.jar under maven